# how to remove \ (backslash ) symbol from string using javascript?

Tags: javascript

**how to remove \ (backslash ) symbol from string using javascript**

```
var str ='Visit\ Microsoft \'; 

var res = str.replace(/\//g, "-");
alert(res);
```

Comment: As posted, your JavaScript string will not have any backslash characters in it (and it's a backslash, not a "slash").  If it did, you'd need to use the regex `/\\/g` to find them.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
str.replace(/\\/g, "-");
```

So you need to use backslash (`\`) instead of forward slash (`/`).

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
var str = 'Visit\\ Microsoft \\';

var res = str.replace(/\\/g, "-");
alert(res);
```

you need to escape the `\` with another `\` as back slash is a escape character, also the regex should be `/\\/g`

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/265Ce/)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach.

```
str = str.split('\\').join('').trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

var str ='Visit\ Microsoft \'; will not work, coz its invalid..

var str ='Visit\\ Microsoft \\'; -- is the correct js string

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed the color change in your HTML Code?

```
var str ='Visit\ Microsoft \'; 

var res = str.replace(/\//g, "-");
alert(res);
```

Everything after Microsoft is red, that indicates everything after Microsoft is also a string.

`\` Backslash works as a **except character**, So it except closing "`'`" mark.

Please check your code, you may need to add backslash before Space, like below

```
var str ='Visit\ Microsoft\ '; 

var res = str.replace(/\//g, "-");
alert(res);
```

This Code will work as you wanted.